# Node styling with data binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to design custom nodes, as shown below:

[image: node image]

I know that `background-image` of the `node` selector can be set to an SVG file, but it's not enough for me: what I need is for the SVG to be data-binded to properties within the node (e.g. the name should come from `data(name)`. Same goes for attributes).

Can I achieve this with cytoscape.js?

**EDIT:**

I tried to use a function that loads the SVG, according to maxkfranz's answer, but it doesn't work for some reason (I get blank nodes):

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: myEles,
    layout: {
        name: 'circle'
    },
    style: cytoscape.stylesheet().selector('node').css({
            'background-color': 'orange',
            'border-width': '6px',
            'background-image': generateSvg,
            'shape': 'roundrectangle',
            'width': '200px',
            'height': '90px'
    })
});

function generateSvg(node) {
    var svg;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/node-image.svg',
        success: function (result) {
            svg = result;
        },
        async: false
    });
    // modify svg
    return svg;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Generate the SVG programmatically.  In the stylesheet: `'background-image': generateSvg` where `generateSvg( node )` reads `node.data()`.

See function mappers: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/mappers

Comment: I tried to do so, but it only displays an SVG if I return a string which is a path to an SVG image. When I try to return an object which holds an SVG, nodes remain blank.

Comment: I don't understand.. On the one hand I can generate the SVG programmatically, but on the other hand, I have to return a URL? Can you post an example for a good `generateSvg( node )`?

Comment: You just need to prepend a string to make an svg a data uri: https://r.va.gg/2012/05/data-uri-svg.html

Comment: OK. I tried that, and got an exception: `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE` from `CRp.safeDrawImage` inside `drawing-images.js` (this is cytoscape.js code). After debugging your code a little bit, I found out that `safeDrawImage`receives an image with a partial data uri as its src attribute (i.e. `"data:image/svg+xml,<svg"`).